# Putting a short into 2 bytes of string

Tags: java, string, actionscript-3, byte, short

So I'm making my own networking protocol for a online game, to save space each message (sent over TCP) is given a ID which is a short, 2 bytes, all messages sent from the server to the client and vice versa are strings, how can I convert a short to a string in java in just 2 bytes (characters)?

**Update:** I'm probably not being clear as to what I want...
I want to be able to convert a short int into 2 characters, so that I can send the short over the network in a string format in just 2 bytes and decode it back into a short on the other side (in actionscript 3).

A character can hold 256 possible values right? So 256*256=65,536 which is the size of a unsigned short int!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static String toCode(int c){

    if(c <= 255 ){
        return Character.toString((char)c);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

public static int fromCode(String c){
    return ((int)c.charAt(0));//Return the character code of the send string, 1 char only
}
```

This can turn a int into a single character which can be sent over the network, now I just need to have it use 2 characters and it can do up to a short.

Comment: you can't - that's why there is `short`in the first place...

Comment: If you are trying to save space, I don't think you should be using strings :)

Comment: A Java `char` is 16-bit, not 8...

Comment: Do have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231051/is-there-a-memory-efficient-replacement-of-java-lang-string . A string in java in just 2 bytes is just impossible.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible to do for some value of "possible".

```
String s = "" + (char)myShort;
```

*However*, the resulting string may be invalid as not all 16-bit integers represent valid (UTF-16 encoded) code-points! That is, the resulting string may be an *invalid* UTF-16 sequence. Various string functions and/or encoding/decode may result in *"strange behavior"* as the fundamental rules have been violated (I think it is somewhat lax as to *what* may occur, but...). You have been warned -- see the bottom example showing just one possible manifestation.

tl,dr. **Don't use strings for this sort of network transmission***. Rather, *use byte arrays* (or ByteBuffers) and send the short as two octets, high and low. (Oh, and did I mention [ByteBuffers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)? Take a look at the methods...) If strings need to be sent they can be encoded (UTF-8) and also sent as "bytes" in the data packets.

Of course, it is quite likely be simpler just to use [standard Serialization](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/SerializeObj.html) or [Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html) to deal with the packets... sure beats custom encoding. (Also, protocol buffers does some neat tricks like zig-zag integer encoding...)

Happy coding :)

---

*Although, Quake 3 use strings for a number of network messages ... however, it encoded the values "as plain text" -- e.g. "xyz=1234" -- and used a bunch of monkey hand-serialization code.

---

See the last value in the output as to why this "string stuffing" can be *bad stuff* ;-)

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        int s1 = 0xd801;
        short s = (short)s1;
        String x = "" + (char)s;
        System.out.println("orig int: " + s1);
        System.out.println("orig short: " + s);
        System.out.println("length of string: " + x.length());
        System.out.println("value in string: " + (short)x.codePointAt(0));
        int s2 = ((short)x.codePointAt(0)) & 0xffff;
        System.out.println("restored value: " + s2);
        byte[] xb = x.getBytes("UTF8");
        System.out.println("encoded size: " + xb.length);
        String x2 = new String(xb, "UTF8");
        System.out.println("decode:" + x2);
        System.out.println("decode length:" + x2.length());
        int s3 = ((short)x2.codePointAt(0)) & 0xffff;
        System.out.println("value in string:" + s3);
    }
}
```

The results in JDK 7, Windows 64.

```
orig int: 55297
orig short: -10239
length of string: 1
value in string: -10239
restored value: 55297
encoded size: 1
decode:?
decode length:1
value in string:63    WHAT IS THIS?!?!?! NOOOOO!!!!!
```

Comment: Oh, please do explain the -1.

Comment: I can't use standard Serialization, as the client will be in flash and server in java, so I'd need some custom serialization.

Comment: @Bubby4j In any case, treat the serialization and transmitted data as a sequence of octects, not a string (at least from Java). I am not sure what support Flash has for byte streams or how it handles strings/string decoding. It might be beneficial to just use a "fat" text-based message format (even, say, JSON) which will be "string safe" unless there is a proven need to encode it into something very compact. Other options include base-encoding of binary data (base64 is common but a custom base96/128 is still be UTF-8 friendly; it doesn't have to be a "readable" encoding, just a "valid" one).

Comment: @Bubby4j "UTF-8 friendly" strings are those in which all (or almost all) characters can be encoded into a single octet; all regular ASCII characters are encoded as a single octet.

Answer (score 1):

DataOutputStream.writeShort/DataInputStream.readShort?

Comment: +1 Very good point -- there be relatively simple methods for serialization streams.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use java, but I think you just want to use a cast operator. If your short is called mynumber, use (char) mynumber. That is, if you then intend to treat those bits as a short when they come out the other side. Good luck with cross-platformness though if you're using "short" as the definition of your field rather than "16-bit signed int", there are some esoteric platforms out there.